# Algorithm for the greatest common denominator

Tags: java, oop, methods, fractions

I have a class `Calculator` which aggregates instances of a class `Fraction` as its attributes.

*Class `Fraction` has attributes `num` for numerator and `denom` for denominator.*

Here is a snippet of the code with `multiply` and `simplify` (to get a fraction in its lowest terms) methods.

```java
public class Calculator {
    private Fraction f1 = new Fraction(4, 9);
    private Fraction f2 = new Fraction(3, 8);

    public void multiply() throws Exception {
        int num = f1.getNum() * f2.getNum();
        int denom = f1.getDenom() * f2.getDenom();
        Fraction f = new Fraction(num, denom);
        simplify(f);
        System.out.print(f);
    }

  private void simplify(Fraction f) throws Exception {
        int num = f.getNum();
        int denom = f.getDenom();
        for (int i = num; i > 0; i--) {
            if ((num % i == 0) && (denom % i == 0)) {
                num = num / i;
                denom = denom / i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I get 12/72 as a result of multiplication while I should get 1/6.
How can I change the code so that `simplify` method works when invoked in `multiply`?

Comment: I believe you need to find the greatest common divisor (gcd) of both the numerator and denominator and use that number to divide both of them. See the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations). Also, `simplify` is something that can probably occur in the `Fraction` class constructor, instead of your `Calculator`. Using that same logic, multiply a Fraction by another is something I would put in the `Fraction` class itself, e.g. in an instance method `Fraction.multiply(Fraction)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Edwin commented you want algorithm for greatest common divisor. However to answer your question, you got unexpected result because the newly computed variables `num` and `denom` at the line with `num = num / i` are not stored back into `Fraction f`.

Either (worse option) call `f.setNum(num); f.setDenom(denom)` or (better) change `Fraction` to immutable class and return new `Fraction` from `simplify` method.